# how to check integrity of recovery partition?

Tags: disk-utility, security, recovery

I recently reinstalled Yosemite from the computer's recovery image.  I'd like to be able to check the integrity of that image (i.e. `shasum /Applications/Install*OS*.app/Contents/SharedSupport/{Base,Install}*.dmg`
 as seen [here](https://github.com/notpeter/apple-installer-checksums).). At the time I could not because `shasum` and most command line utilities are not installed when you boot from the recovery partition.  I know there is a volume called `Recovery HD` but I can't access it.  How do I check the integrity of the installer on the recovery partition?

Thank you

Comment: The Apple installer creates the recovery partition.  If your checksum is good for the installer, then the recovery partition it creates will be good.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount the Recovery volume in your normal booted macOS.

```
diskutil mount readOnly Recovery
```

Then you can perform checksums on files as you normally would, on the Recovery volume.

```
shasum /Volumes/Recovery/*/BaseSystem.dmg
```

When you're done, you can unmount Recovery.

```
diskutil unmount Recovery
```